# Get the SyncParameters values from webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ext.net

I have a gridpanel with the store like this,

```
  <Store>
                                <ext:Store ID="strAltMenu" runat="server">
                                         <Proxy>
                                <ext:AjaxProxy Json="true" Url="~/XAdisyonWebService.asmx/AltMenuGetir">
                                    <ActionMethods Read="POST" />

                                    <API Create="~/XAdisyonWebService.asmx/AltMenuEkle"></API>
                                    <API Update="~/XAdisyonWebService.asmx/AltMenuGuncelle"></API>
                                    <API Destroy="~/XAdisyonWebService.asmx/AltMenuSil"></API>
                                    <API Sync="~/XAdisyonWebService.asmx/AltMenuGetir"></API>
                                    <Reader>
                                        <ext:JsonReader Root="d" />
                                    </Reader>
                                    <Writer>
                                        <ext:JsonWriter Encode="true" Root="data" />
                                    </Writer>
                                </ext:AjaxProxy>
                            </Proxy>
                                   <SyncParameters>

                <ext:StoreParameter Name="test" Value="App.hdnId.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
            </SyncParameters>
```

my question is how I cann get the value of the StoreParameter inside the SyncParameters from the webservice 
thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define it in a WebMethod's signature.

```
<SyncParameters>
    <ext:StoreParameter Name="someParam" Value="someValue" Mode="Value" />
</SyncParameters> 

[WebMethod]
public object SaveSuppliers(string data, string someParam)
```

Also, as an alternative, you should be able to take it directly from a Request object.

Comment: I am using asmx web call daniil

Comment: Hmm, I am also using a WebMethod (from a WebService) in my example.